# SVN - Merge working copy into another branch

Tags: svn, merge, branch, trunk, working-copy

I started doing a bunch of changes in a branch that should have happened in trunk. I have not committed those changes yet, so my branch has a bunch of uncommitted files.

Trunk shares a same revision as the branch that contains my uncommitted code so it should merge nicely.

Is there a good way to merge my working copy into trunk instead of the branch? I do not want to affect the branch at all.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [svn switch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html) to change the path that your working copy points to. After svn switch, just commit your changes.

Comment: This worked for me -- mostly. I actually had to merge HEAD from my branch into trunk first and as a second step, switch my working copy to trunk and commit. This lead me through to the right conclusion though. Thanks!